# Java applet "Invalid top level statement" error

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am making a maze game in java using applets and I implemented a switch case on my image so that if I win I can go to the next image. But when I try to run it in the interactions panel (because the image is too big for the default applet size) using 
import edu.rice.cs.plt.swing.SwingUtil; SwingUtil.showApplet(new mazeGameTest(), 700, 700); 
it gives me an error saying Invalid top level statement.

```
 Image backImage; 
 BufferedImage image=null;
 int[] dataBuffInt;
switch(flag){
  case 0: try { 
image = ImageIO.read(new File("firstMaze.jpg")); 
} 
catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("image did not load"); }
  break;
  }
dataBuffInt = image.getRGB(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height, null, 0, this.getSize().width);
```

I searched the internet but their solution doesn't solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"searched the internet but their solution doesn't solve this problem."*  If the entire internet cannot solve this problem, what makes you think we can?  ;) BTW - the internet is a big place.  What is the link of this 'solution that did not work'?  1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: we're still in high school so he's teaching us the simple stuff I guess. and the main one I saw was this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408710/java-error-invalid-top-level-statement but I don't think that its the solution

Comment: *"..he's teaching us the simple stuff I guess.."*  You and he guessed wrong, and it is time he found out the error of his ways and stopped subjecting students to the torture of applet development.  Challenge the teacher to produce an applet, *any applet* that the class can visit on the web.  That might knock some sense into him.  But definitely refer him to that link I provided earlier.